# Laravel -: "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given" in Leave request

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I was trying to submit staff leave request into the database. I have 2 tables basically:

1. hr_leave_requests
2. hr_holidays

   protected $fillable = [
             'holiday_name',
             'holiday_date',
             'created_at',
          ];

Controller

```
public function store(StoreLeaveRequestRequest $request)
{
        $commencementDate   = Carbon::parse($request->commencement_date);
        $resumptionDate     = Carbon::parse($request->resumption_date);
        $holidays           = DB::table('hr_holidays')->select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
        $days = $commencementDate->diffInDaysFiltered(function (Carbon $date) use ($holidays) {
            return $date->isWeekday() && !in_array($date, $holidays);
        }, $resumptionDate);  
        $leaverequest = HrLeaveRequest::create([
            'leave_type_id'             => $request->leave_type_id,
            'commencement_date'         => $commencementDate,
            'resumption_date'           => $resumptionDate,  
            'no_of_days'                => $days,
        ]);    
        Session::flash('success', 'Leave Request is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');               
}
```

View

```
   <form  action="{{route('service.leave_requests.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Leave Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Leave Type" tabindex="1" name="leave_type_id" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="">Select Leave Type</option>
                    @if($leavetypes->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($leavetypes as $leavetype)
                            <option value="{{$leavetype->id}}">{{$leavetype->leave_type_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Commencement Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="commencement_date" value="{{old('commencement_date')}}"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>                    
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Resumption Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="resumption_date" value="{{old('resumption_date')}}"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div> 

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="submit_create" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
    </div>           

    </form>
```

I want the application to get no_of_days by taking the difference between resumption_date and commencement_date in the hr_leave_request table and also exclude weekends. Then go to hr_holiday table and get the public holiday within the leave days.

I used this for that:

```
$days = $commencementDate->diffInDaysFiltered(function (Carbon $date) use ($holidays) {
            return $date->isWeekday() && !in_array($date, $holidays);
```

NB: See the complete code in the controller

When I submitted, I got this error:

> "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given"

How do I resolve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is returned cause the table response is a collection.

Try to replace this

```
$holidays = DB::table('hr_holidays')->select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
```

with this

```
$holidays = DB::table('hr_holidays')->select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get()->pluck('holiday_date')->toArray();
```

Comment: how about if the holiday dates are two dates (start_date and end_date) instead of a single date (holiday_date)

Comment: in that case I guess you would need a different approach, like building an array with all the holiday dates and then compare it in the in_array function